# How to update a variable outside a function using a function which takes inputs and conditions the output for the variable. I am using PHP

Tags: php

I am making an semi-automatic attendance register so that whenever a person submits his or her name a table will get updated and change their status.

Here is the code for the form which I made:

```
<form  action="Attendance.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name of 
Employee" style="width: 210px;"><br>
    <input type="number" name="refNo" placeholder="Reference 
Number of Employee" style="width: 210px;" disabled="disabled"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
```

Here is the code I wrote which is a function. This function checks if the person present or not and change a variable that imports its value from the form I mentioned above:

```
<?php
function check_attendance($eNAME, $NAME, $eNUM){
    if ($eNAME == $NAME) {
        $eNUM = 'Present';
    }
    else{
        $eNUM = 'Absent';
    }
}
$eNAME = $_POST['name'];
//$eNAME is the name of the employee given in form I wrote above.
$eNUM1 = '';
//$eNUM1 is the status of the employee that is whether an employee is present or absent.
check_attendance($eNAME, 'John D', $eNUM1);

echo $eNUM1;
?>
```

I have yet not written the code to integrate the person being present or absent into a table.

I cannot get to update $eNUM1 using function check_attendance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of achieving this, the first using virtually the same code as you have is to [pass the variable by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)...

```
   function check_attendance($eNAME, $NAME, &$eNUM){
```

this allows the function to alter the value in the calling scope.

BUT

As you want to just set a value from the function, it would be better(IMHO) to just return the value...

```
   function check_attendance($eNAME, $NAME){
        if ($eNAME == $NAME) {
                $eNUM = 'Present';
        }
        else{
                $eNUM = 'Absent';
        }
        return $eNUM;
   }
   $eNAME = $_POST['name'];
   //$eNAME is the name of the employee given in form I wrote above.
   //$eNUM1 is the status of the employee that is whether an employee is present or absent.
   $eNUM1 = check_attendance($eNAME, 'John D' );

   echo $eNUM1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return $eNum

```
<?php
function check_attendance($eNAME, $NAME, $eNUM){
if ($eNAME == $NAME) {
$eNUM = 'Present';
}    else{
 $eNUM = 'Absent';
  }
return $eNUM;
}
$eNAME = $_POST['name'];
//$eNAME is the name of the employee given in form I wrote above.
$eNUM1 = '';
//$eNUM1 is the status of the employee that is whether an employee is present or absent.
$eNUM1 = check_attendance($eNAME, 'John D', $eNUM1);
echo $eNUM1;
?>
```